# How to reset all activities and launch a new one?

Tags: android

I have an application in which i want to navigate this way:

A -> B -> C

And from C launch a new activity called D, that goes to top and also clears the task, meaning that if i press back on D it goes to home screen.

If i understand it correctly this FLAG: FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME does this... but it's only on current APIs (11>).

I'm developing for Android 1.5> how can i also have this behaviour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are looking for this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, activityClass);
ComponentName cn = intent.getComponent();
Intent mainIntent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(cn);
activity.startActivity(mainIntent);
```

use android compatibillity lib from google - found in the sdk.

or use `finish()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` along with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

> public static final int FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
>
> Since: API Level 11
>
> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will
>   cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to
>   be cleared before the activity is started. That is, the activity
>   becomes the new root of an otherwise empty task, and any old
>   activities are finished. This can only be used in conjunction with
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up using this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8576529/327011 as I needed to use it from 1.5 > and that flag is only avaliable on higher APIs.

If I hadn't the need to support "low" API levels the answer from @aromero would be my option.

Comment: As this answer is outdated i've accepted @A. Binzxxxxxx as the most up-to-date (but haven't tried his code yet).