# Android close all activity when sing out

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app have a sign in activity. If login is successful, I start the first activity. It includes the menu, which opens ActivityA, ActivityB, ActivityC... and from these activities I can go deeply ActivityASubA and deeper ActivityASubB...

```
-ActivityA
--ActivityASubA
--ActivityASubB

-ActivityB
--ActivityBSubA
--ActivityBSubB

...
```

And if the user open ActivityA and ActivityASubA and later from the menu ActivityB and after that sign out, I open the sign in activity, but in the history will be the previous activities and if he press back see again these activities and it's a problem.

So when sign out I need to close all activity. Which is the best solution?

Comment: I think the same approach as in  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486865/remove-or-close-your-own-activity-window-from-a-status-bar-notification-intent/  
can be followed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sign out method you should put this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);  
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  
startActivity(new Intent(this, Home.class));  
finish();
```

About FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP you can read th

Comment: How it works? If a click sign out and use your code it's won't clear history, so I can back to the previous activities

Comment: @Robertoq flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP clear stack untill called Activity.